# Gulp plugin: splitting a Vinyl file into multiple files doesn't properly divide data

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I have a Gulp plugin, `stratic-paginate-indexes`:

```
'use strict';

var through2 = require('through2'),
    path = require('path');

function makePage(originalFile, page, pageNumber) {
    var newFile = originalFile.clone();
    newFile.data = newFile.data || {};
    newFile.data.posts = page;
    newFile.data.page = pageNumber;

    if (pageNumber === 1) return newFile;

    var filePath = path.parse(newFile.path);
    filePath.dir = path.join(filePath.dir, 'page', pageNumber.toString());
    newFile.path = path.format(filePath);

    return newFile;
}

module.exports = function() {
    return through2.obj(function(file, enc, callback) {
        var pageNumber = 1,
            pageFiles = [],
            page = [];

        while (file.data.posts > 0) {
            page = file.data.posts.splice(5);

            var newFile = makePage(file, page, pageNumber);
            pageFiles.push(newFile);

            pageNumber++;
        }

        // Per-index page counts
        pageFiles.forEach(function(file) {
            file.data.pageCount = pageFiles.length;
            this.push(file);
        }, this);

        callback();
    });
};
```

This plugin is designed to take in Vinyl files representing blog post indexes. For an index `file`, `file.data.posts` is an array of Vinyl files representing individual posts to be included on the rendered page. Here's the Gulp task I'm using this in:

```
var jade = require('gulp-jade');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var remark = require('gulp-remark');
var remarkHtml = require('remark-html');
var adjustHeaders = require('remark-rewrite-headers');
var parse = require('stratic-parse-header');
var dateInPath = require('stratic-date-in-path');
var postsToIndex = require('stratic-posts-to-index');
var paginateIndexes = require('stratic-paginate-indexes');
var addsrc = require('gulp-add-src');


gulp.task('post-index', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/blog/*.md')
               .pipe(parse())
               .pipe(remark().use(remarkHtml).use(adjustHeaders))
               .pipe(dateInPath())
               .pipe(addsrc('src/blog/index.jade'))
               .pipe(postsToIndex('index.jade'))
               .pipe(paginateIndexes())
               .pipe(jade({pretty: true, basedir: __dirname}))
               .pipe(rename({ extname: '.html' }))
               .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/blog'));
});
```

However, this setup isn't actually outputting any index pages at all.

Originally, the logic in the `while` loop you see there was implemented using `Array.prototype.forEach` and `Array.prototype.shift`:

```
file.data.posts.forEach(function(post) {
    page.push(post);

    if (page.length === 10) {
        var newFile = makePage(file, page, pageNumber);

        pageFiles.push(newFile);

        page = [];
        pageNumber++;
    }
});

// Handle the last page which won't have 10 posts (and so will fail the above `if` test)
if (page.length > 0) pageFiles.push(makePage(file, page, pageNumber));
```

This did in fact create index files, but with *super* weird `file.data.posts` values. If I recall correctly it *looked* like each page's `file.data.posts` was set to the last couple posts (i.e. the value of the final page's `file.data.posts`) but I'm not positive that's what was happening.

Anyway, I'm kind of at a loss. This seems like real simple code to me, and I've spent a *lot* of time fruitlessly trying to debug.

(Note that I'm also the author of several other plugins in the pipeline. It *may* be that I did something dumb in those that's causing this mysterious error. Everything in the Gulpfile is published on npm with the obvious exception of `stratic-paginate-indexes`, so feel free to take a look at the other modules if that's where the problem's coming from.)

**Edit:**

After fixing some bugs pointed out in answers, the implementation is now this:

```
while (file.data.posts.length > 0) {
    page = file.data.posts.splice(0, 5);

    var newFile = makePage(file, page, pageNumber);
    pageFiles.push(newFile);

    pageNumber++;
}
```

However for some reason this leads to an infinite series of pages being output, each with the same first 5 elements of the original `file.data.posts`. Almost like I was using `Array.prototype.slice` (except obviously I'm not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
var newFile = originalFile.clone();
```

Unfortunately, the Vinyl documentation for the `.clone()` function is incorrect (at least for Vinyl 0.4.x, which is what you get with Gulp 3). The docs state that `.clone()` does a deep-clone, but it actually does a shallow-clone. Using [black magic](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/B/black-magic.html), you can force the call to do a deep-clone:

```
var newFile = originalFile.clone(true);
```

See [gulpjs/vinyl#125](https://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl/issues/125).

Answer (score 1):

> For an index file, `file.data.posts` is an array of Vinyl files representing individual posts

If that's true then your problem is the following two lines:

```
while (file.data.posts > 0) {
  page = file.data.posts.splice(5);
```

In the first line you're comparing **the array itself** with 0. You need to compare the `length` of the array instead:

```
while (file.data.posts.length > 0) {
```

That isn't enough though. In the second line you're calling [`Array.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) with a single argument. That will remove everything but the first 5 elements from `file.data.posts`, so `file.data.posts.length` would perpetually stay at 5. Boom. Infinite loop.

If I'm understanding you correctly you want to partition the array into groups of 5. In that case the second line should be this:

```
  page = file.data.posts.splice(0, 5);
```

That will put the first 5 posts into `page` and remove them from `file.data.posts`.

Comment: *sigh* this is what I get for writing code at 2 AM. nice catch! however this still doesn't solve my problem - I'll edit the new code into my question

Comment: Whatever problem you still have can't be reproduced with the code in your question. You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: can you clarify what you think is missing/incorrect? I'm happy to edit the question but I'm not sure what you're looking for

Comment: Create a new project from scratch that only contains the things in your question, nothing else. Can you reproduce the problem? If no, your question is missing stuff.